# How to fill values in an array?

Tags: php

I have following code. What i want to do is to check`$altOwnerEmail[$keys[$j]]`to it's previous value. I f they are same then store them in an array, if not then create a new array. I am a beginner. Please help.

```
for ($j = 0; $j < count($keys); $j++) {

    if ($altOwnerEmail[$keys[$j]] != $to[$keys[$j]]) {  
        $altOwnerEmail=$altOwnerEmail[$keys[$j]];
        $accessEmailDifferent[$l] .= $accessEmailMainSection[$keys[$j]];    
    }

}
```

Comment: `$altOwnerEmail[] = $altOwnerEmail[$keys[$j]]`

Comment: Please, add some context (for example, sample data for variables `$keys`, `$to`, `$altOwnerEmail`, `$accessEmailDifferent`, `$l`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assiging the new entry to the array variable itself, thereby replacing the whole array with a single value.

```
$myArray = array(); // Empty array
$myArray[] = "abc"; // contains now one entry
$myArray[] = "def"; // now two entries
$myArray = "xyz"; // now it is not an array any more, $myArray is just a plain string.
```

Solution: use the `$myArray[] = ...` syntax.